How to update a specific row's value in an Angular table with duplicate data using (change) event?
I am working on an Angular project where I have a table generated using *ngFor. The table rows represent objects in an array, and the data can have duplicate entries (same name or other properties). Each row has an input field that allows the user to change a specific property (e.g., leverage).
Here’s an example of my table structure:
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Leverage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of m_backtestedBenchmarks; let i = index">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          [value]="item.leverage"
          (change)="onLeverageChange($event, i)"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Here’s my TypeScript logic to handle the change:
onLeverageChange(event: Event, index: number) {
  const newValue = parseFloat((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.trim());
  if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
    this.m_backtestedBenchmarks[index].leverage = newValue;
    console.log('Updated array:', this.m_backtestedBenchmarks);
  }
}

However, my data can have duplicate rows, like this:
m_backtestedBenchmarks = [
  { name: "Portfolio A", leverage: 1.25 },
  { name: "Portfolio A", leverage: 1.25 }
];

In this scenario, the (change) event sometimes updates both rows instead of just the one the user interacted with. I want to ensure that only the row corresponding to the user’s input is updated, even if the rows share the same data (e.g., duplicate name or other properties)
My Questions:
How can I ensure that only the specific row being edited gets updated when duplicates exist?
Is the (change) event with [value] the right approach for this scenario? If not, what would be a better Angular-idiomatic way?
Are there any best practices or considerations for handling updates to arrays with duplicate objects in Angular?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

the problem lies in how you are creating the array could you share that code

Like I said in the comments, the problem is how the data is created, the issue I feel is that, you are creating the array m_backtestedBenchmarks with shared memory references, so even through your code is correct, due to shared memory references it is giving the impression that the code has a bug.

Explanation:
Remember arrays and objects are stored as references in memory, so suppose you have a complex object or array and you share this reference between two variables, the updates in one variable get copied to another due to shared memory references. Below is a working example demonstrating this principle.


const a = {
  test: 1,
  asdf: {
    qwer: 1,
  },
}

const b = a; // assign a to b

// now try modifying the b variable.

b.asdf.qwer = 1000;
console.log(a);

console.log(b);



So the solution is to create a copy, which is of two types, shallow copy and deep copy, the first one clones only upto one level, but deep copy clones every level.


const a = {
  test: 1,
  asdf: {
    qwer: 1,
  },
}

/* shallow copy */
const b = { ...a
}; // shallow copy

// now try modifying the b variable.

b.test = 1001;
b.asdf.qwer = 1000;
console.log(a);

console.log(b);
// notice that a is not updated for `test`
/* shallow copy */


/* deep copy */
const c = structuredClone(a); // shallow copy

// now try modifying the c variable.

c.test = 1001;
c.asdf.qwer = 1000;
console.log(a);

console.log(c);
/* deep copy */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}




You can simply use Two Way binding with [(ngModel)] instead of [value] and (change).
Here is how it will look:


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Leverage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of m_backtestedBenchmarks; let i = index">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          [(ngModel)]="item.leverage"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Also make sure to import FormsModule to use NgModel.

How can I ensure that only the specific row being edited gets updated when duplicates exist?
i only wnat to update one specific row where the user changed not all the  rows?

You are referencing an item from your table through its index. It's better to reference by the index object instead. This way, if by any reason your indexes alter before finishing the change of your input, any bad thing will happen. I agree with Danish on the [(ngModule)] thing. You should catch those errors as a form error handler. Watch the documentation for that. Angular's form validation
Also, I would recommend to change the type="text" to `type="number".
